# How to connect Python Elasticsearch client to Bitnami ELK VM?

Tags: python, bitnami

Bitnami ELK running in VMWare player (15). Can ping the machine. Trying to connect with ElasticSearch client from Python, cannot, while can ping. Already changed Bitnami Config and restarted (https://docs.bitnami.com/ibm/apps/elk/administration/connect-remotely/) any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Took me several hours to find this, hope this helps someone

When using the Bitnami VM ELK for VMWare player Machines, you must open firewall,and must update config to run publish_host on the public interface, and also update kibana config yml to keep kibana working. More details below.

https://community.bitnami.com/t/unable-to-access-port-9200-or-5601-from-outside-the-virtual-machine/88040
https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/elasticsearch/administration/control-services/
https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/elasticsearch/administration/connect-remotely/
https://community.bitnami.com/t/cannot-connect-to-elasticsearch/75146/4